# Stream/Download file without keeping in memory in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, google-cloud-storage

My application uses Google Cloud Storage for storing large files and Spring Boot as backend.

I just finished implementing the controller responsible for the download, following what I thought could be correct, but the behavior I am getting from the browser is not what I expected.

**The Steps**

If I try to download a file, the following will happens:

1. The file ("blob") is read from google cloud storage using a ReadChannel
2. The channel write to a ByteArrayOutputStream;
3. The channel writes using a buffer
4. The ByteArrayOutputStream is converted in a InputStreamResource
5. The inputStream Resource is then passed in the ResponseEntity

**The Unexpected Behavior**

If a user goes to the controller of the download, and ask for a specific file, the file is first loaded completely on the server, and then served to the client. In the meanwhile, the client sees like the server "not responding" (because the server is loading the file), which is not nice. When the file is then completely loaded on the server, is gonna appear in the "Downloaded" really fast.

**What I wanted**, was to avoid the "not responding" part, and stream or the file to the client, like does it happens normally when you try to download a large file, that you see a "downloading" wheel around the file in Chrome.

Any help understanding what's wrong with the following code would be appreciated!

The code for the Sring controller is the following:

```
@RequestMapping("/**/*")
    public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> downloadFile(
                RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
                String fid = ....
                WritableByteChannel channel;

                    Storage storage = new DownloadAction().getStorage();
                    BlobId blobId = BlobId.of(BUCKET_ID, blobPath);
                    Blob blob = storage.get(blobId);
                   

                    ByteArrayOutputStream writeTo = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    try (ReadChannel reader = blob.reader()) {
                        channel = Channels.newChannel(writeTo);
                        ByteBuffer bytes = ByteBuffer.allocate(64 * 1024);
                        while (reader.read(bytes) > 0) {
                            bytes.flip();
                            channel.write(bytes);
                            bytes.clear();
                        }
                    }

                    channel.close();
                    writeTo.close();

                    InputStream tmp = new ByteArrayInputStream(writeTo.toByteArray());
                    InputStreamResource resource = new InputStreamResource(tmp);
                    MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parseMediaType(mimeType);
                    return ResponseEntity.ok()
                            .contentType(mediaType)
                            .contentLength(fileSize)
                            .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"")
                            .body(resource);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
            }

    }
```

Comment: Well obviously you are reading it into memory first, why.. Just directly stream to the `OutputStream` of the response instead of your own output stream.

Comment: Hate my life! Thank you, managed to make it work!

Comment: @M.Deinum I know it's been a long time since a comment, but I wonder if you directly stream to the `OutputStream` of the resposne, does it still somehow store parts of the object in the memory/on a disk? Is there a chance that if you stream a big file in such a way - you can have your memory filled up?

Or does it completely skip storing in memory/on a disk on the server when you stream directly into the response?

Comment: @THEWaterfall I know is a long time, and hopefully Denium will also answer. Personally, my answer is the following: in a computer with shared resources there is always something that will be stored in memory. You cannot suppose that the BUS will be free at all time, that the L0 memory will be available or that the Processor is ready to take over your request. Concluding, yes, small parts will be locally processed and put in a hopefully fast memory. And remember there are registers that make out computers work.. and those are memory locations

Comment: @BioShock, Can you please tell, what were the changes required in the above code. I am also searching solution for the exact same thing as yours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your question, the objects in your bucket are private and you want to give access to them for the limited group of people. 
If so - the Signed URL's are what you need.

You can generate signed URL for a particular object in a bucket and redirect your user to generated URL - so he will download the file himself.

More info: [GCloud Signed URLs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls)

Comment: I want them to always go through the server, for any download, and use the server as "middleware" between the user that wants to download the file and the storage. I don't want them to download the file himself, actually, I want to hide completely the storage from the users.

Comment: So, that's what signed URLs for. You can generate signed URL available to a particular user. So this user can only download a particular object(file) - for example he cannot browse your butcket. Also signed URLs have a time limitation, after some time, specified by you - the URL becomes unavailable (invalid).